# Sending Mail with System.Net.Mail working in Mono, not in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, mono, smtp

I searched the other questions on StackOverflow but could not find a solution to my problem.

I want to send a mail, using System.Net.Mail and C#. The Mailserver is given by an institute of the university (with SSL (SHA1), Unix-machine). I have used the same code on different machines. The code is working on Debian and Ubuntu with Mono. On Windows 10 and Windows Server 2012 (current .NET) it is not working. I get the error:

```
554 5.7.1 : Client host rejected: Access denied
```

Using Thunderbird on the Windows Machine also works for connecting. So the Mailserver and Credentials are correct. Is use the following code:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(MailFrom, "*****@gmail.com");
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Port = MailPort;
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Host = MailSMTPHost;
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(MailUser, MailPass);
client.EnableSsl = true;
mail.Subject = "Testmail";
mail.Body = "Fooobar!";
mail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
mail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
try
{
    client.Send(mail);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Failed: "+e.Message);
}
```

Do you have any idea, what is going on?

Thank you all!

Comment: I don't know but suspect that this will be something to do with the way in which the `MAIL FROM` message is sent to the SMTP server by Mono vs native .Net.  `554 5.7.1` is usually given when your from email address is blocked - this is usually for one of two reasons: either you have been blacklisted, or your from address is invalid.  Try change the from address to something that is compatible with the SMTP server you are using and you may find it is resolved.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I checked this with our admins - The email provided is correct and neither the Mailserver, client nor address is blacklisted in any way. Is there any way to try other encodings or transports for the From-Field in the .NET connection to the Mailserver? (It is a Unix-mailserver)